# CKEditor and HTML in Xpages

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

I am understanding this better but still not there yet. 
I have a notes document with a rich text field. I want to edit it in Xpages, so that the user can enter text for an email that an agent will generate. The idea is that the user should be able to enter styled text, hopefully including pasted graphics, and this is saved to the rich text field in such a way that a later agent can copy that field to the body of an email.

On the form I have checked the field "Store contents as HTML and MIME.

In the Xpage I have bound the CKEditor directly to the field (can bind it to a scope variable if necessary).

The code in my agent is as follows:

```
Set rtItmFrm = emlDoc.getFirstItem("Body")
Set rtItmTo = New NotesRichTextItem(mail,"Body")
Set rtItmTo = rtItmFrm.Copyitemtodocument(mail,"Body")
```

Any further suggestions on reading up on MIME/CKEditor etc would also be much appreciated.

Bryan

=========================================================================
I just discovered how to modify the CKEditor in Xpages (the Rich Text Control). I have the full menu and one or two more things turned out. However, I am really puzzled by how it treats HTML. I would like to put a template for a nice HTML email (like a newsletter). Anything even a little complicated it munges and the output is messed up.

I read enough online to understand that it is not supposed to be a HTML editor, but I am really having trouble getting the results I want. I would love to put some basic skeleton HTML in there, but everything but the simplest code doesn't work.

Is there anyway to import HTML and it not get messed up using this editor?

Comment: This might be useful: http://xpagetips.blogspot.dk/2013/10/add-custom-html-templates-to-your.html

Comment: That helps somewhat. I could make one and put it in there. But I would really like to be able to generate an HTML email without the limitations in CKEditor.

Comment: You can use the "Source" button in the toolbar to switch to the HTML source and edit your HTML directly there

Comment: Yes, that is good, EXCEPT when I save the document, CKEditor changes my HTML. I do not want it to change my HTML. If it would not do that then I would be so damn happy. Is there an easy way to turn that off, Per?

Comment: Perhaps it's filtering? Try turning off filtering on the rich text control. A wild shot

Answer (score 1):

as Per and Stephan said, Have a look at ACF filtering that is 'server side' (This is not related to CKEditor itself, but it is related to XPages).

If you have a look at the inputRichText control you will see 2 properties.

- htmlFilter
- htmlFilterIn

These properties determine how to filter Html on the way in to your data, and also on the way out.
This can be used to strip styling out, and also to prevent dangerous tags like  some bad code here etc.

By Default the htmlFilter is set ACF (Active Content Filtering) if you look at the default rules, you will see it strips things like 'margin' out.
see /properties/acf-config.xml-sample

There is a filter called 'identity' which means don't filter anything, however beware if you use this you are not protected from and maliciously entered html.

You should look into defining your own set of rules for your ACF filter, this way you can choose which elements to remove. There is a section in Mastering XPages book about this.

If you still have any trouble, then there are some settings in CKEditor config which also control ACF (totally separate to XPages server side)

Comment: Cameron, I have modified my original question to more precisely explain why I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Bryan, my answer is still the same. I think that the html filtering is taking place server side. have a look at the XPages ACF. did you attempt using Identity filter?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CKE changes the HTML, it is the writing back to a RT field.

Try and bind your RichText Editor to a scoped variable instead of a RichText field. This way you have access to the raw HTML and can use that to generate a MIME email. You might want to have a look at Mustache for mail merge.

Use [this article series](http://notessensei.com/blog/2014/04/ckeditor-and-mustache-become-friends.html) as starter how to prepare CK editor to make this possible.

And as Per mentioned: check the filtering.

Comment: I have modified my question to more accurately define what I am trying to do. The link is much appreciated.